# How to change example block body text size in beamer?

Tags: beamer

If I compile the following code, I get a slide where the normal block body text size is tiny as written in the code, while the body text size of example and alert block doesn't change.

I've also tried other combinations of `\setbeamerfont`, but none of them are able to change the body text size of example and alert blocks.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\Huge}

\setbeamerfont{block body}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{block title example}{size=\Huge}
\setbeamerfont{block body example}{size=\tiny}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{exampleblock}{Title}
    Test
  \end{exampleblock}
  \begin{alertblock}{Title}
    Test
  \end{alertblock}
  \begin{block}{Title}
    Test
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Item
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With template `block body alerted` you will change example and alerted block body fonts. According to the manual `block body example` should be used to fix example body font, but with Frankfurt theme it didn't work.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\Huge}

\setbeamerfont{block body}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{block title example}{size=\Huge}
\setbeamerfont{block body alerted}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{block body example}{size=\Huge}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{exampleblock}{Title}
    Test
  \end{exampleblock}
  \begin{alertblock}{Title}
    Test
  \end{alertblock}
  \begin{block}{Title}
    Test
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Item
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]